# Ошибка в функции перевода римского числа в десятичную систему счисления

Tags: haskell

Написал 4 функции для нахождения суммы римского числа с двоичным, оба переводятся в десятеричную и затем складываются.Проверил отдельно все функции, ошибка появляется только в `romeToInt` .

Вызываю функцию в терминале : `romePlusDec "X" "101"` и в терминале появляется такая ошибка : `non-exhaustive patterns in romeToInt`. Что в ней не так ?

```
romeDig :: Char -> Int
romeDig 'I' = 1
romeDig 'V' = 5
romeDig 'X' = 10
romeDig 'L' = 50
romeDig 'C' = 100
romeDig 'D' = 500
romeDig 'M' = 1000
```

```
romeToInt :: [Char] -> Int
romeToint [x] = romeDig x
romeToInt (x:y:xs)
    | romeDig x < romeDig y = romeToInt (y:xs) - romeDig x
    | otherwise = romeToInt (y:xs) + romeDig x
```

```
binToDec [] = 0
binToDec (x:xs) =  digitToInt(x) * (2^(length xs)) + (binToDec xs)
```

```
romePlusDec :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Int
romePlusDec a b = romeToInt a + binToDec b
```

Comment: Нет пустого списка в шаблоне?

Comment: не совсем понял

Comment: Что-то типа `romeToint [] = 0`

Comment: Но я не настоящий хаскелист ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: опечатка romeTo**i**nt

Comment: спасибо большое, не заметил сразу